# How to fix Clean and build project netbeans error

Tags: java, netbeans, build-impl.xml

Im getting an error like below when clean and build the project

```
> javac: invalid target release: 15 Usage: javac <options> <source
> files> use -help for a list of possible options
> C:\Users\Shehan Rathnayake\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Sesatha\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\Shehan Rathnayake\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Sesatha\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

These are the lines
xml:930 - <j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
xml:270 -

Comment: Are you using and to build this project?

Comment: Yes @Dora apache-ant-1.10.9

Comment: Can you try using Maven, I had a similar problem and I had to use Maven to resolve it.

Comment: @Dora I'll check and get back to you. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "invalid target release" should actually be coming from the java compiler. You can indeed create Java source code for e.g. Java 11 and compile it such that the bytecode would also execute on Java 8. Now for some reason these parameters are weirdly setup in your case.

- check your project properties/Sources page. In the bottom you can check the source/binary format.
- check your project properties/Build/Compile page. It shows the Java Platform used to compile the code.

If you cannot figure out meaningful values, list what you have and let us know how you want it to be compiled and run afterwards.